# Effectively iterate over two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

Currently i am fiddling around with two dimensional arrays for learning purposes, and have arrived at a problem i can't see a solution to.

The goal is to build the following output (see grid further down)

```
0.0: 0.1
1.0: 1.1
2.0: 2.1
3.0: 3.1
4.0: 4.1

0.0: 0.2
1.0: 1.2
2.0: 2.2
3.0: 3.2
4.0: 4.2
ect
```

I believe i have achived this by the following piece of code.

```
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

//grid1[0].length = 7

for (int col = 0; col < (grid1[0].length - 1); col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid1.length; row++) {
            sb2.append(grid1[row][0] + ": ");
            sb2.append(grid1[row][col+1] + newline);
        }
        sb2.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    System.out.println(sb2.toString());
```

My question is, if it's possible to achieve the same goal by running over the array in a reverse order (see below), and if their is a more efficient way that what i have arrived to.

```
for (int row = 0; row < grid1.length; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < grid1[0].length; col++) {
      //something
   }
}
```

The grid - array[5][7]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use :

```
for (int row = grid1.length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (int col = grid1[0].length - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I tried this and it show me :

```
int grid1[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
for (int row = grid1.length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (int col = grid1[0].length - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
        System.out.print(grid1[row][col]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

9 8 7 
6 5 4 
3 2 1
```

Instead of :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But wouldnt this also give me the values from right to left instead of left to right?

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk check my edit, i tried this example and it work fine